# list unique file names in a specific folder applescript

Tags: applescript

I need to list all of the unique file names in a specific folder in AppleScript.

The only problem is that the filenames will all be in this format - L58478_A_2803

I need to be able to ignore everything after the first underscore.

Comment: The question is unclear. File names in a folder are required to be unique.

Comment: The number at the send is a sequential number which increases as a new file is added to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to tell me whether this is what you were after or not.  Given the following files in the folder `"~/Example"`:

```
L58478_B_2803.txt
L58666_B_2803.txt
L58478_A_2804.txt
L58666_B_2804.txt
L58478_A_2803.txt
L58666_A_2803.txt
```

the script identifies the leading portion of the filename and picks out the unique identifiers for those groups of files.  The result, in this case, would be `{"L58478", "L58666"}`.

```
use application "System Events"
property text item delimiters : "_"

script filenames
    property list : name of files in folder "~/Example" whose visible = true
end script

tell (a reference to the list of filenames)
    repeat with f in it
        set f's contents to text item 1 of f
    end repeat

    repeat with i from 1 to (its length) - 1
        set [x, x_] to its [item i, items (i + 1) thru -1]
        if x is in x_ then set its item i to null
    end repeat

    strings
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the files in the folder are.. {"L58666_B_2803.txt", "L58666_B_2804.txt", "L58666_B_2805.txt", "L58666_B_2806.txt", "L58667_B_2807.txt", "L58668_B_2806 .txt"}

This following script

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set fileNames to name of files of (choose folder)
end tell

set partialNames to {}

repeat with i from 1 to count of fileNames
    set thisItem to item i of fileNames
    set theOffset to offset of "_" in thisItem
    set newName to text 1 thru (theOffset - 1) of thisItem
    if partialNames does not contain newName then
        set end of partialNames to newName
    end if
end repeat
```

Would return... {"L58666", "L58667", "L58668"}  If you do not want to include the first "_"

However, If you do  want to include the first "_"

Change

```
set newName to text 1 thru (theOffset - 1) of thisItem
```

To

```
set newName to text 1 thru theOffset of thisItem
```